# Xcode tvOS - Error: You don’t have permission to save the file “fileName.txt” in the folder “Documents”

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tvos

I have an Xcode tvOS project in Objective-C. 
I'm trying to save a sample fileName.txt file into the Documents folder with this code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self applicationDocumentsDirectory];

    NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory].relativePath
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fileName.txt"];
    NSString* sampleText = @"Prova";
    NSError* err;
    [sampleText writeToFile:path atomically:YES
                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
    if(err != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
}

/**
 Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
    inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
         inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}


@end
```

But I get this error when I run the app: **Error: You don’t have permission to save the file “fileName.txt” in the folder “Documents”.**

In iOS it works instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have access to Documents on tvOS.

Here is from Apple (see for details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241)):

> Local Storage for Your App Is Limited
>
> - The maximum size for a tvOS app bundle 4 GB. Moreover, your app can
>     only access 500 KB of persistent storage that is local to the device
>     (using the NSUserDefaults class). Outside of this limited local
>     storage, all other data must be purgeable by the operating system when
>     space is low. You have a few options for managing these resources:
> - Your app can store and retrieve user data in iCloud. Your app can
>     download the data it needs into its cache directory. Downloaded data
>     is not deleted while the app is running. However, when space is low
>     and your app is not running, this data may be deleted. Do not use the
>     entire cache space as this can cause unpredictable results.
> - Your app
>     can package read-only assets using on-demand resources. Then, at
>     runtime, your app requests the resources it needs, and the operating
>     system automatically downloads and manages those resources. Knowing
>     how and when to load new assets while keeping your users engaged is
>     critical to creating a successful app. For information on on-demand
>     resources, see On-Demand Resources Guide. This means that every app
>     developed for the new Apple TV must be able to store data in iCloud
>     and retrieve it in a way that provides a great customer experience.