# Saving files via C's fopen on tvOS

Tags: c, tvos

On iOS I'm using the Documents folders to save persistent files of my app. But on tvOS [it isn't available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980516/647898). Using `NSUserDefaults` is only a key value store and my app is an existing code base written in C.

Is there a way to keep using C's `FILE`-like API for saving?